# The convergence of $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{(m^2+1)^k}{k^m}$, and a related series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like refresh my mathematics in Calculus. I have the following

> **Question.** Can you compute or at least give a reasoning about the convergence of this series
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\log\left(\frac{m^2+1}{m^2}\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{m}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{(m^2+1)^k}{k^m}\right)?$$
>   As I've said there is no problem if only you can provide to me the behaviour of such series. Is convergent? Why? My goal is encourage to study more mathematics. **Thanks in advance.**

By he way that I've deduced the series I believe that is convergent, I don't do any succesful attempt to solve this. I believe that I have to start with

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m^2+1)^k}{k^m}$$ 
and study for which integers $m\geq 1$ is convergent this series using a criterion, thus $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{(m^2+1)^k}{k^m}$ should be convergent.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m^2+1)^k}{k^m}$ converges for no $m$. The terms blast off to $\infty.$

Comment: Very thanks much, then my claim is the baddest. Thanks @zhw

Comment: I'm sorry all users for this bad claim, I convinced myself of the convergence such series by my computations. Very thanks much another time to **zhw**, and **Nima**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $m = 1$ we have $(m^2 + 1)^k = 2^k > k$ for any $k$.

For $m > 1$ we have $m^2 + 1 > m$ and since $m^k > k^m$ for large enough $k$, it follows $(m^2 + 1)^k > k^m$. This means, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(m^2+1)^k} {k^m} > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1 = + \infty,$$ so the series diverges for all $m \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Very thanks much, then my claim is the baddest. Very thanks much @NimaBavari

Comment: You're welcome @Juan happy New Year!

Comment: Thanks to you and a Happy New Year! @NimaBavari